# Sending a Message to All Browsers using Java based socket io client for netty

Tags: java, socket.io, netty

I'm currently trying to send a message to all the browsers form java based client for socket io [socket.io-netty](https://github.com/ibdknox/socket.io-netty).But currently it is sending message to only one browser at a time.
the snippent is following:

```
public class IOClientListener implements INSIOHandler {
    private INSIOClient ioClient=null;
    private final static Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(IOClientListener.class);

    @Override
    public void OnConnect(INSIOClient client) {
        System.out.println("A user connected :: " + client.getSessionID());
                client.send("Hey you are connected to myhope.com");

    }

    @Override
    public void OnDisconnect(INSIOClient client) {
        System.out.println("A user disconnected :: " + client.getSessionID() + " :: hope it was fun");  
    }

    @Override
    public void OnMessage(INSIOClient client, String message) {
        System.out.println("A message received:: " + message + " :: hope it was fun");
    }

    @Override
    public void OnShutdown() {
    }

    public INSIOClient getIOClient(){
        return this.ioClient;
    }
}
```

I want to know how to broadcast the message using this client. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Netty ChannelGroup for this purpose

```
....
 static ChannelGroup allClientChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup();


 @Override
public void OnConnect(INSIOClient client) {
    System.out.println("A user connected :: " + client.getSessionID());
            client.send("Hey you are connected to myhope.com");

   allClientChannels.add(client.getCTX().getChannel());
}


@Override
public void OnDisconnect(INSIOClient client) {
    System.out.println("A user disconnected :: " + client.getSessionID() + " :: hope it was fun");
    allClientChannels.remove(client.getCTX().getChannel());

}
```

...

```
//when you want to send a broadcase message

allClientChannels.write(yourMessage);
```

For more detail, have a look on [ChannelGroup API Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html)

Comment: I've tried this and I've written allClients.write(message) but I receive "IllegalArgumentException: unsupported message type: ...". How do you send message?

Comment: the message should be a channel buffer, I am not familiar with socket.io, I guess it might support pipeline of handlers like in Netty, so you have to have a encoder handler after the broad cast handler, then send the message after encoding it to a channel buffer object.